# Overriding where signin-oidc callback redirects after succeded authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, load-balancing, openid-connect

I'm hosting an ASP.NET Core 2.x web app behind a load balancer. Let's say the public url is `public_url.com`. Internally, the app is in `private_url.com/iis_sub_dir`.

I could do this setup by adding a custom BasePath middleware first thing in the pipeline.

**The Problem:**
After logging in using OpenIdConnect middleware towards an external provider, it returns to my `/signin-oidc` callback path successfully with 302 response code, but the response header "location" is like: `public_url.com/iis_sub_dir/etc`.
That iis_sub_dir ruins everything and I get 404.

I tried to add another custom middleware, but it seems that this request/response is not being passed to it!

Main config:

```
                .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = xxx;
                    options.ClientId = xxx;
                    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
                    options.CorrelationCookie.Path = "/"; // cookie + load balancer fix
                    options.NonceCookie.Path = "/"; // cookie + load balancer fix
                    options.ResponseType = "code";
                
                
                    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                    {
                        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async (ctx) =>
                        {
                            ctx.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = publicPath + CallbackPath;

                            await Task.FromResult(0);
                        },
```

PathBase middleware:

```
httpContext.Request.PathBase = new PathString(baseRedirectPath);
```

I simply want to remove that iis_sub_dir from the "location" response header of CallbackPath endpoint.

Thanks.

Comment: Try this -  options.CallbackPath = "/iis_sub_dir/signin-oidc"; It should work.

Comment: It doesn't work unfortunately, still getting the iis_sub_dir in the location header which I want to get rid of.

Answer (score 4):

While using the **OpenId Connect Authentication Scheme**, make use of the `RedirectUri` property.

```
await HttpContext.ChallengeAsync("OpenId-SchemeName",
  new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "http://public-url.com/iis_sub_dir/signin-oidc" });
```

See the documentation here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.authentication.authenticationproperties?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Thank you for that.
I've got the returnUrl as a parameter to my login action like this: `public async Task Login(string returnUrl)`.
Works fine when you actually pass the returnUrl, but gets stuck in a redirect loop if you don't.
Changed it to `public async Task Login(string returnUrl = "/")`.